# Как работают маски в BMP изображениях?

Tags: c++, изображения, bmp

Я пытаюсь написать примитивные алгоритмы для чтения изображений различных форматов в массив байтов. После того, как получилось разобрать PPM и TGA рисунки, решил приступить к формату BMP.
На данный момент я научился преобразовывать BMP изображение в массив RGB последовательностей в следующих случаях:

- В рисунке информация о конкретном пикселе кодируется при помощи
  четырех или восьми бит, и при этом в файле присутствует таблица
  цветов (Color Table).
- В рисунке  информация о конкретном пикселе    кодируется при помощи
  двадцати четырех бит, и при этом файл не    содержит таблицу цветов.
  Это наиболее простой вариант.

Проблемы возникли с 32-битными BMP изображениями.
Я генерирую BMP файлы при помощи графического редактора Paint dot NET. В окне с параметрами сохранения можно выбрать значение битности рисунка. Мое 32-битное изображение имеет размер 2*2 px и выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пиксель №1 имеет цвет RGB(11, 12, 13), пиксель №2 – RGB(51, 52, 53), пиксель №3 – RGB(101, 102, 103), пиксель №4 – RGB(151, 152, 153).

С помощью класса `std::ifstream` и его метода `get()` я вывел содержимое файла в консоль (сначала идет номер байта, затем содержимое байта с этим номером):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тот же самый вывод, но текстом:

```
1) 66   2) 77   3) 166   4) 0   5) 0   6) 0   7) 0   8) 0   9) 0   10) 0   11) 150   12) 0   13) 0   14) 0   15) 124   16) 0   17) 0   18) 0   19) 2   20) 0   21) 0   22) 0   23) 2   24) 0   25) 0   26) 0   27) 1   28) 0   29) 32   30) 0   31) 3   32) 0   33) 0   34) 0   35) 0   36) 0   37) 0   38) 0   39) 196   40) 14   41) 0   42) 0   43) 196   44) 14   45) 0   46) 0   47) 0   48) 0   49) 0   50) 0   51) 0   52) 0   53) 0   54) 0   55) 0   56) 0   57) 255   58) 0   59) 0   60) 255
61) 0   62) 0   63) 255   64) 0   65) 0   66) 0   67) 0   68) 0   69) 0   70) 255   71) 32   72) 110   73) 105   74) 87   75) 0   76) 0   77) 0   78) 0   79) 0   80) 0   81) 0   82) 0   83) 0   84) 0   85) 0   86) 0   87) 0   88) 0   89) 0   90) 0   91) 0   92) 0   93) 0   94) 0   95) 0   96) 0   97) 0   98) 0   99) 0   100) 0   101) 0   102) 0   103) 0   104) 0   105) 0   106) 0   107) 0   108) 0   109) 0   110) 0   111) 0   112) 0   113) 0   114) 0   115) 0   116) 0   117) 0   118) 0   119) 0   120) 0   121) 0   122) 0   123) 0   124) 0   125) 0   126) 0   127) 0   128) 0   129) 0   130) 0   131) 0   132) 0   133) 0   134) 0   135) 0   136) 0   137) 0   138) 0   139) 255   140) 0   141) 0   142) 0   143) 0   144) 255   145) 0   146) 0   147) 0   148) 0   149) 255   150) 0   151) 103   152) 102   153) 101   154) 255   155) 153   156) 152   157) 151   158) 255   159) 13   160) 12   161) 11   162) 255   163) 53   164) 52   165) 51   166) 255
```

Поле, которое занимает с 15-го по 18-й байт (в зависимости от версии BMP называется bcSize/biSize/bV4Size/bV5Size) имеет значение 124, что соответствует версии BMP 5. Это говорит о том, что рисунок может содержать *«битовые маски для извлечения значений каналов: интенсивность красного, зелёного, синего и значение альфа-канала»* (источник: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#BITMAPINFO). На наличие масок также указывает значение поля Compression (с 31-го по 34-й байт), так как оно равно числу 3. Поля, содержащие маски, занимают 4 байта и идут друг за другом начиная с 55-го байта. Судя по консольному выводу, в моем изображении маски имеют следующие значения (десятичная система счисления):

Маска **красного** цвета: `0 0 255 0` (с 55-го по 58-й байт)

Маска **зеленого** цвета: `0 255 0 0` (с 59-го по 62-й байт)

Маска **синего** цвета: `255 0 0 0` (с 63-го по 66-й байт)

Маска **альфа-канала**: `0 0 0 255` (с 67-го по 70-й байт)

Я не могу понять, как интерпретировать эти значения и применять их к цветам пикселей, которые расположены в конце файла. Если я буду игнорировать эти значения и извлеку цвет напрямую (из блока данных, который иногда называют Image Data или Pixel Data), то получу верные цвета. Должно быть, так происходит из-за того, что в графическом редакторе я не корректировал маски, и программа записала для них значения по умолчанию, которые не искажают цвет пикселей.

Если поправить значения масок вручную и перезаписать файл, то цвет каждого пикселя изменится. Например, я заменил маску красного цвета на `0 0 60 0` (десятичная система счисления), открыл изображение в графическом редакторе и получил такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пиксель №1 теперь имеет цвет RGB(34, 12, 13), пиксель №2 – RGB(204, 52, 53), пиксель №3 – RGB(153, 102, 103), пиксель №4 – RGB(85, 152, 153).

Действительно, поменялось значение красного цвета у каждого пикселя. Наверное, редактор выполняет какие-то операции с бинарными представлениями чисел, но я не знаю, какие именно. В статьях о BMP, которые я видел, маски почему-то упоминаются как-то вскользь. Вопросы вызывает также блок данных, расположенный до Image Data. Он занимает с 139-го по 150-й байт файла (в моем случае) и, согласно Википедии, имеет название GAP1 (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BMPfileFormat.svg?uselang=ru). GAP1 появился в моем BMP рисунке только после того, как я выставил значение битности на 32 в параметрах сохранения. Данные этого блока очень напоминают цветовые маски, но я не уверен, что это имеет какую-нибудь связь, так как я не смог найти информацию о GAP1. Наверное, я делаю что-то не так.

Пожалуйста, скажите, как понять принцип работы масок в BMP рисунках?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void ReadImage_BMP(const char* file_path_c_str);

int main()
{

    ReadImage_BMP(".../image.bmp");

    return 0;
}

void ReadImage_BMP(const char* file_path_c_str)
{
    std::string file_path = file_path_c_str;

    std::ifstream input_fs;
    input_fs.open(file_path, std::ios_base::binary);

    if (input_fs.is_open() == false)
    {
        perror(("Error while opening file " + file_path).c_str());
        return;
    }

    char current_byte;
    int count = 1;

    while ((bool)input_fs.get(current_byte) == true)
    {
        std::cout << count << ") " << (int)(unsigned char)current_byte << std::endl;
        count++;
    }

    if (input_fs.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "End of file reached." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (input_fs.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Type error." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
    }

    input_fs.close();

}
```

Comment: Стандартный порядок цветов в 32 bpp bitmap - BGRA. Судя по приведенному вами описанию, маски `FF000000 (B), 00FF0000 (G), 0000FF00 (R), 000000FF (A)` соответствуют этому порядку. Новый стандарт позволяет эти маски менять, то есть старый стадарт это теперь частный случай нового. Сначала обработайте каждую маску, определите, сколько битовых нулей в конце. Например, Для стандартного случая, `shift_b=24, shift_g=16, shift_r=8, shift_a=0`. Затем читаете каждый пиксель в `uint32_t n`, и вычисляете цвета: `r=(n&mask_r)>>shift_r, g=(n&mask_g)>>shift_g...`

Comment: Если маска содержит больше 8 битов, а вывод на экран поддерживает 8 битов, надо еще одно преобразование. Например, маска содержит 10 бит, тогда каждый цвет `n` надо сдвинуть вправо на 2 бита. И наоборот, если маска содержит меньше 8 битов, надо сдвинуть влево. Напримем, для маски в 7 битов каждый цвет должен быть сдвинут влево на один бит. Итак, поработайте с маской, прежде чем читать пиксели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модифицированная вами структура масок - нестандартная. Можно предположить, что разные программы будут по разному обрабатывать такой файл.
Попробуем вникнуть, что происходит у вас.

По логике, если у нас 4-х битная маска (0x3C), то значение красного компонента не должно превышать 15 (в десятичной с/с).

Поэтому я решил проанализировать двоичное представление.

**Пиксель №1**
RGB(11, 12, 13) или 0x0D0C0BFF (+ альфа-канал)
Маска: `00 00 60 00` или 0x00003C00

В двоичном виде:

```
00001101000011000000101111111111
00000000000000000011110000000000
```

Биты под маской: **0010**
Paint dot NET даёт нам: **00100010** (34)

Видно, что левые 4 бита идентичны правым и соответствуют битам под маской.
**Можно предположить**, что биты под маской были скопированы влево до заполнения 8 бит.

---

**Пиксель №2** (0x353433FF)

```
00110101001101000011001111111111
00000000000000000011110000000000
```

Биты под маской: **1100**
Заполняем до 8-бит: **11001100** (254)

---

**Пиксель №3** (0x676665FF)

```
01100111011001100110010111111111
00000000000000000011110000000000
```

Биты под маской: **1001**
Заполняем до 8-бит: **10011001** (153)

---

**Пиксель №4** (0x999897FF)

```
10011001100110001001011111111111
00000000000000000011110000000000
```

Биты под маской: **0101**
Заполняем до 8-бит: **01010101** (85)

---

Таким образом, предположение подтвердилось.
Почему именно так? Ума не приложу.
Скорее всего, единого стандарта здесь нет и каждая программа интерпретирует это по своему. В спецификации, которую я читал, есть только одно требование: биты в маске должны быть непрерывны и маски не должны перекрываться.

Учитывая, что 99.99% файлов будут со стандартными масками, можно не переживать на этот счет, хоть и любопытно очень...

---

**UPD**
Если предположение выше верно для любой маски, то могу предложить такой код для получения компоненты по маске:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

unsigned long getPixelComponentByMask(unsigned long pixel, unsigned long mask);

int main()
{
  unsigned long pixel = 0x0D0C0BFF;
  unsigned long mask  = 0x00003C00;

  std::cout << getPixelComponentByMask(pixel, mask) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

unsigned long getPixelComponentByMask(unsigned long pixel, unsigned long mask)
{
  if(pixel > 0 && mask > 0) {
    unsigned long p, m, firstBit, n = 0, out = 0;
    
    while(n < 8) {
      p = pixel;
      m = mask;

      while(m > 0) {
        if(m & 1) {
          firstBit = p & 1;
          out ^= (-firstBit ^ out) & (1UL << n);
          n++;
        }

        p >>= 1;
        m >>= 1;
      }
    }
    
    return out;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Если нужно, могу добавить комментарии к коду.

Answer (score 2):

Вот программа с необходимыми функциями и тестами. Для работы нужны структуры и функции `compute_mask_info`, `compute_pixel`. Читая файл, посчитайте 4 `mask_info` для каждого цвета. Затем читайте пиксели и обрабатывайте их с помощью `compute_pixel`.

Программа не учитывает endianness компьютера, на котором она выполняется. Оставляю вам для развлечения.

Читайте также мои комментарии под вопросом, чтобы понять, для чего это нужно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


struct mask_info
{
    uint32_t value;             // mask
    int placement_shift;        // shift right to this value after applying the mask
    // 8 bits normalization: > 0 - shift right to this value, < 0 = shift left to this value.
    int normalization_shift;    
};

struct pixel_info
{
    uint32_t value;             // actual value
    uint32_t normalized_value;  // normalized to 8 bit, for 8 bpp display
};

mask_info compute_mask_info(uint32_t mask);
void print_mask_info(const mask_info& info);
pixel_info compute_pixel(uint32_t value, const mask_info& info);

int main()
{
    uint32_t masks[] =
    {
        // Standard masks
        0xFF000000,
        0x00FF0000,
        0x0000FF00,
        0x000000FF,
        // Non-standard masks
        0x000003FF,         // normalization 2 expected
        0x0000007F,         // normalization -1 expected
        0x00003FF0,         // placement 4, normalization 2 expected
        0x00007F00          // placement 8, normalization -1 expected
    };

    // Test masks
    for(auto n: masks)
    {
        auto mi = compute_mask_info(n);
        print_mask_info(mi);
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Test pixels, standard masks
    {
        uint32_t pixel = 0xA1B2C3D4;

        mask_info mi[] =
        {
            compute_mask_info(masks[0]),        // blue
            compute_mask_info(masks[1]),        // green
            compute_mask_info(masks[2]),        // red
            compute_mask_info(masks[3])         // alpha
        };

        for(const auto& minfo: mi)
        {
            auto p = compute_pixel(pixel, minfo);

            cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << p.value << "  " << setw(2) << p.normalized_value << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Test pixels, non-standard masks
    {
        uint32_t pixel = 0x00003FF0;             // expected output with masks[6]: 3FF FF

        auto p = compute_pixel(pixel, compute_mask_info(masks[6]));

        cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << p.value << "  " << setw(2) << p.normalized_value << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

pixel_info compute_pixel(uint32_t value, const mask_info& info)
{
    pixel_info pi{};

    pi.value = (value & info.value) >> info.placement_shift;
    pi.normalized_value = pi.value;

    if (info.normalization_shift > 0)
    {
        pi.normalized_value >>= info.normalization_shift;
    }
    else if (info.normalization_shift < 0)
    {
        pi.normalized_value <<= info.normalization_shift;
    }

    return pi;
}

void print_mask_info(const mask_info& info)
{
    cout << "0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(8) << info.value << dec << "  " << info.placement_shift << "  " << info.normalization_shift << endl;
}

mask_info compute_mask_info(uint32_t mask)
{
    mask_info mi{};
    mi.value = mask;
    int bit1_count{};       // number of set bits

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        if (mask & (1<<i))
        {
            ++bit1_count;
        }
        else
        {
            if (bit1_count)
            {
                break;          // this is 0 after mask, stop here
            }

            ++mi.placement_shift;
        }
    }

    mi.normalization_shift = bit1_count - 8;

    return mi;
}
```

Для полноты картины, вывод программы:

```
0xff000000  24  0
0x00ff0000  16  0
0x0000ff00  8  0
0x000000ff  0  0
0x000003ff  0  2
0x0000007f  0  -1
0x00003ff0  4  2
0x00007f00  8  -1

a1  a1
b2  b2
c3  c3
d4  d4

3ff  ff
```

Answer (score 1):

GAP1 - это просто дырка, которая появляется, если массив пикселей смещен на расстояние большее, чем размер заголовка (например для целей и выравнивания). Маски - это обычные битовые маски которые применяются через AND + смещение к цвету пикселя из массива для получения значения.

Comment: Уже долго думаю, но не могу понять, что значит "применяются через AND + смещение к цвету пикселя". Я знаю про побитовое И (AND), но к чему именно его нужно применить? Цвет пикселя в таблице: `0000 1011`, маска: `0011 1100`. `0000 1011` & `0011 1100` = `0000 1000`, что пока не позволяет мне понять логику. По поводу смещения, оно означает побитовый сдвиг? Прошу прощения за такие глупые вопросы, но я буду очень рад, если Вы скажите об этом немного подробнее

Answer (score 1):

Это изображение, из [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) хорошо объясняет что такое битмаски, т.е. они определяют каким образом будут хранится биты цвета (там где 1 будет информация о соответствующем цвете) и таким образом весь файл и формируется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом я предполагаю что поменяв маски цветов местами можно поменять сами цвета - это легко проверить.

Так же из [документации](https://docs-microsoft-com.translate.goog/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapv5header?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) можно подчерпнуть что:

`bV5RedMask`

Цветовая маска, указывающая красный компонент каждого пикселя, действительна только в том случае, если для параметра bV5Compression установлено значение BI_BITFIELDS.

`bV5GreenMask`

Цветовая маска, указывающая зеленый компонент каждого пикселя, действительна только в том случае, если для параметра bV5Compression установлено значение BI_BITFIELDS.

`bV5BlueMask`

Цветовая маска, определяющая синий компонент каждого пикселя, действительна только в том случае, если для параметра bV5Compression задано значение BI_BITFIELDS.

`bV5AlphaMask`

Цветовая маска, определяющая альфа-компонент каждого пикселя.

**Демонстрация** по смене цвета (меняю местами маску зеленого и красного)

Оригинальное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С измененной маской:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как было произведена замена (оригинал)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Битовые операции AND**

Как известно, эти операции очень хорошо позволяют извлекать части чисел, итак у нас есть массив пикселей
по 3-4 байта на пискель в зависимости от битности изображения

[[255,255,255], [0,100,200] ... тут я обозначил группы доп скобками

В `hex` представлении это `0xFFFFFF` и `0xС86400` соответсвенно (учитывая обратную запись байтов в файле)

А в хэдере битмапа лежат наши маски к примеру такие:

- `0xFF0000` - red
- `0x00FF00` - green
- `0x0000FF` - blue

Таким образом байты `0xС86400` разложаться на:

- `0xС86400` & `0xFF0000` -> `0xC80000` -> `0xC8` (R)
- `0xС86400` & `0x00FF00` -> `0x006400` -> `0x64` (G)
- `0xС86400` & `0x0000FF` -> `0x000000` -> `0x00` (B)

**Как именно получаются новые цвета**

И напоследок, я написал небольшую программку для экспериментов с битами, можно добиться очень интересных эффектов перемешивая их, своеобразный вариант шифровки изображений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я видел этот рисунок, но он не помог мне понять, как именно получаются новые цвета моего изображения. Например, изначальное значение красного цвета моего пикселя было равно `0000 1011` (dec: 11). Маска `0011 1100` (dec: 60) как-то преобразовала это значение в `0010 0010` (dec: 34). `0000 1011` & `0011 1100` = `0000 1000` (dec: 8), что не равно конечному значению цвета. Наверное, я не понимаю какую-то базовую вещь или допускаю где-то глупую ошибку, поэтому ничего не получается

Comment: можете скинуть куда-нибудь 32 битмап? я не могу найти и скажите номер старт байтов для масок если не сложно, я продемонстрирую

Comment: уже не нужно сделал

Comment: таким образом маска определяет в каком порядке и битовом объеме будут браться цвета

Comment: А как 13-битная компонента выводится на экран? По модулю 255?

Comment: Cкорее всего как-то обрубается до 8 бит, это сложно глазом заметить